# Unity punch coroutine not finishing

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, coroutine

So I have the code as follows.

```
void Update() {

        // WASD Movement
        if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.W)) { movementUpdate.y += movementPerSecond * Time.deltaTime; }

        if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.A)) { movementUpdate.x -= movementPerSecond * Time.deltaTime; }

        if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.S)) { movementUpdate.y -= movementPerSecond * Time.deltaTime; }

        if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.D)) { movementUpdate.x += movementPerSecond * Time.deltaTime; }

        playerBody.position = playerBody.position + movementUpdate;

        movementUpdate = new Vector3(0, 0, 0);

        // Body rotation relative to cursor position

        Vector3 dir = Input.mousePosition - Camera.main.WorldToScreenPoint(transform.position);
        float angle = Mathf.Atan2(dir.y, dir.x) * Mathf.Rad2Deg;
        playerBody.rotation = Quaternion.AngleAxis(angle - 90, Vector3.forward);

        // hand position via function
        UpdateHandPosition(playerLeftHand, desiredPositionForLeftHand);
        UpdateHandPosition(playerRightHand, desiredPositionForRightHand);

        if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0)) {
            Punch();
        }

    }
...

void Punch() {
        StartCoroutine(PunchCoroutine());
    }

IEnumerator PunchCoroutine() {
        Debug.Log("User punched.");

        if (onLeftHandPunch = false) {
            print(onLeftHandPunch);

            onLeftHandPunch = false;

            // punch the shit

            desiredPositionForLeftHand = "middleMiddleCoordinates";

            yield return new WaitForSeconds(1f);
            Debug.Log("Corountine finished.");

            desiredPositionForLeftHand = "topMiddleCoordinates";



        } else {
            print(onLeftHandPunch);

            onLeftHandPunch = true;

            // punch the shit

            desiredPositionForRightHand = "middleMiddleCoordinates";
        }



    }
```

But when I play the code, and click the left mouse button, the following is displayed in the console.

```
User punched.
False
```

The Coroutine won't finish and display

```
Coroutine finished.
```

Can somebody help me out here? I think the issue is at the yield WaitForSeconds area, but I don't know. I've looked at other code samples, and it should be working correctly. Hopefully you guys have some answers.

Answer (score 1):

The other answer is correct in that the issue is the `if (onLeftHandPunch = false)` line, but the logic is incorrect as to why...

Your original code:

```
if (onLeftHandPunch = false) {

} else {

}
```

Will always run the `else` part, because it sets `onLeftHandPunch` to `false`, and then evaluates the if statement. That results in `if (false)` which means that the `else` will be run.

The fix is simple, use the `==` comparison operator instead of the `=` assignment operator:

```
if (onLeftHandPunch == false) {

} else {

}
```

Your coroutine is finishing, but you only print "Coroutine finished" in the first "if" statement and not in the "else". If you moved it outside the `if` statement to the bottom, you would see that the coroutine is indeed "finishing", but not running the logic that you want.

Answer (score 0):

In your if statement, `if (onLeftHandPunch = false)`, you're actually setting your variable to false. You should be using the ' == ' operator. As it is, that will always be true as it can always set the variable to false. Also, you might want to change the WaitForSeconds(1f) to WaitForSeconds(1.0f), Unity tends to like that a little better.

Hope this helps.